# SQL Count and Group By

Tags: sql-server

There are 5 columns in my table

```
Name, UserID, Depertment, JobCode, Template
```

I want to find the `Count(Template) Group By Department and JobCode` but want to select other columns too.

My query is:

```
Select UserID, Department, JobCode, Template, Count(Template)
From MyTable
Group By Department, JobCode
```

Getting error:

> UserID is invalid in selection list because it is not in the Group By
>   list.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data and why you want the results to be?

Comment: When you use aggregate, you need to select only the column in the aggregation or aggregate functions like _count_ or _avg_. If you want to display other fields, they need to fulfill one of the previous statement.

Answer (score 0):

For Transact SQL, as one of your tags identifies, you must use all selected columns in some fashion when grouping.

For this, you must either use columns in a function (`COUNT`, `MAX`, `AVG`, etc.) or you must group by them.

Grouping will still give you the columns, however:

```
SELECT UserID,
       Department,
       JobCode,
       Template,
       COUNT(Template)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY UserID, Department, JobCode, Template
```

This will give you the columns you've selected, and will give the number of Templates based on the grouping. So for each distinct group of `UserID`, `Department`, `JobCode`, and `Template`, it will give you a count.

If you don't care to distinguish by Template, remove it from the select list, but keep it in the `COUNT` function.

Conversely, you could use rownumber and partition over the column you would like to group by I am using a Common Table Expression to do this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  UserID, 
            Department, 
            JobCode, 
            Template, 
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Template)
    FROM myTable
)
SELECT  UserID, Department, JobCode, Template
FROM    CTE
WHERE   RowNum > 0;
```

The RowNum column would give you the enumeration of the number of times the Template appeared given the other columns. For example, you might have `UserID = 5`, `Department = 5`, `JobCode = 5`. You might then have 3 rows which appear to be duplicates on these columns, however `Template` will be different. In this example, it would equal `Template = 32`, `Template = 4`, and `Template = 101`. The `RowNum` column would increase by 1 for each row, so you would have a total of 3. See below:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| UserID | Department | JobCode | Template | RowNum

| 5      | 5          | 5       | 32       |  1

| 5      | 5          | 5       | 4        |  2

| 5      | 5          | 5       | 101      |  3
```

Comment: I want to show all the columns but want to calculate the count Grouping By only Department and JobCode. How do I do that?

Comment: In that case, you would use rownumber, and partition over your column. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, if you are using an aggregator then you must include all fields but the calculated field in a group by.

```
CREATE TABLE #TemplateCount
(UserId INT , 
 Department VARCHAR(10) , 
 JobCode INT , 
 Template VARCHAR(10) )


 INSERT INTO #TemplateCount (UserId, Department, JobCode, Template)
 VALUES (1 , 'HR' , '12345' , 'A') , 
        (2 , 'HR' , '12346' , 'B') , 
    (3 , 'HR' , '12347' , 'C')

SELECT UserID ,
   Department , 
   JobCode , 
   Template ,
   TemplateCount = COUNT(Template)

 FROM #TemplateCount
GROUP BY UserId , Department , JobCode , Template
```